# What is the minimum (differential) entropy at a given variance?

Tags: entropy, multivariate-normal-distribution, maximum-entropy, multivariate-distribution

Given a set of samples $S$ from an unknown multidimensional real-valued distribution, I use the multivariate normal distribution $N(\mu(S),\Sigma(S))$ to compute its upper entropy limits. This is possible, since the normal distribution is the maximum entropy probability distribution for a given variance $\Sigma(S)$.

Is there is a way to compute the lower entropy limit given $S$? Assuming $|S|>1$, i.e., the entropy is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum entropy distribution for a given non-zero variance is a Bernoulli distribution with $p \to 0$ or $p \to 1$ ([Is there a minimum entropy distribution for a given variance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279090/))

Therefore range of entropies that can be obtained for a given variance are bounded by $0$ below (the Bernoulli distribution) and by $0.5 \sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} + 0.5$ above (the normal distribution).

The lower bound is not inclusive however. We can not exactly obtain the zero entropy.